# Laravel : throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);

Tags: laravel-5

After much research on this forum, but elsewhere on the Internet, "Cat got your tongue".

Many messages speak about this subject, but I can not correct my mistake on my side.

I use the same form to add or modify my data.

I have an error with my form only when I want to modify my data.

Wep.app :

```
// Gérer les personnes (sociétés, personnes...) photographiées
Route::get('tiers', 'tiersController@afficheliste'); // Fait
Route::get('tiersajouter', 'tiersController@ajouter'); // Fait
Route::post('tiersmodifier', 'tiersController@modifier'); // Fait
Route::post('tiersupdatesql', 'tiersController@updatesql'); // Fait
Route::post('tierssupprimer', 'tiersController@supprimer'); // Fait
Route::post('tiersreactiver', 'tiersController@reactiver'); // Fait
```

ctrltiersRequest :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ctrltiersRequest extends FormRequest {
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
     public function rules() {
          return [
               'tiersNom'      => 'required|min:5',
               'ville'         => 'required',
               'tiersiptc1'    => 'required',
               'tiersiptc2'    => 'required'
          ];
     }
     public function messages() {
          return [
               'tiersNom.required'       => "Le nom est obligatoire",
               'tiersNom.min'            => "Le nom doit faire au minimum 5 caractères",
               'ville.required'          => "La ville est obligatoire",
               'tiersiptc1.required'     => "Le thème principal est obligatoire",
               'tiersiptc2.required'     => "Le sous-thème est obligatoire"
          ];
    }
}?>
```

tiersModif.blade :

```
I can not paste the contents of my blade file into this message. I add it in a reply to this message. I am sorry...
```

tiersControllers :

```
 public function updatesql(ctrltiersRequest $request) {
    //public function updatesql(tiersRequest $request) {
         //['tiers_id' => (int)$request->tiersModif],
        $tiers = tiers::updateOrCreate(
            ['tiers_id' => $request->tiersModif],
            ['tiers_nom'                => $request->tiersNom,
             'tiers_prenom'             => $request->tiersPrenom,
             'tiers_societeproduction'  => $request->production,
             'tiers_ville'              => $request->ville,
             'tiers_iptc1'              => $request->tiersiptc1,
             'tiers_iptc2'              => $request->tiersiptc2,
             'tiers_iptc3'              => $request->tiersiptc3]);
        // Afficher
        return Redirect('tiers');
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the blade file:

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('style')
    <link href="{{ asset('css/grid.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
        .navbar-template {
            padding: 40px 15px;
        }
    </style>
@endsection

@section('bardemenu')
    @include('menu')
@endsection

@section('contenu')
    @if ( $Action['Action'] == "Ajouter" )
        <h4>&nbsp;Ajouter un tiers (artiste, photographe, club...)</h4>
        @if ($errors->any())
            <ul>{!! implode('', $errors->all('<li style="color:red">:message</li>')) !!}</ul>
        @endif
        <form method="POST" action="{!! url('tiersupdatesql') !!}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            &nbsp;<label for="Nom">Nom :&nbsp;</label><input name="tiersNom" type="text" id="tiersNom" maxlength="50" size="50"><br>
            &nbsp;<label for="Prenom">Prénom :&nbsp;</label><input name="tiersPrenom" type="text" id="tiersPrenom" maxlength="50" size="50"><br>
            &nbsp;<label for="Production">Société de production :&nbsp;</label><input type="radio" name="production" value="0" checked>&nbsp;Non (par défaut)&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="production" value="1">&nbsp;Oui<br>
            @if ( $boiteprod->count()==0 )
                &nbsp;<label for="Production">Pas de boite de production dans la base.</label>
            @else
                &nbsp;<label for="Production">Manager par la boite de production :&nbsp;</label>
                <select name="production" id="production">
                    <option value="">--- choisir une boite de production ---</option>
                    @foreach ($boiteprod as $bprod)
                        <option value="{{ $bprod->tiers_id }}">{{ $bprod->tiers_nom }} {{ $bprod->ville_name }} ({{ $bprod->zip_code }})</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            @endif
            <br>
            <label for="ville">&nbsp;Ville :&nbsp;</label>
                <select name="ville" id="ville">
                    <option value="">--- choisir une ville ---</option>
                    @foreach ($villes as $ville)
                        <option value="{{ $ville->ville_id }}">{{ $ville->ville_name }} ({{ $ville->zip_code }}), {{ $ville->namedept }}-{{ $ville->nom_fr_fr }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select><br>
                <label for="tiersIPTC1">Thème :&nbsp;</label>
                    <select name="tiersiptc1" id="tiersiptc1">
                        <option value="0">Choisissez un thème principal</option>
                        @foreach ($iptc1s as $iptc1)
                            @if( !empty($MetadataSeance[0]->metadata_Id) )
                                <option value="{{ $iptc1->IPTC1_Id }}" {{ ($iptc1->IPTC1_NomFR==$MetadataSeance[0]->comadobecategory) ? "selected=selected" : '' }}>{{ $iptc1->IPTC1_NomFR }}</option>
                            @else
                                <option value="{{ $iptc1->IPTC1_Id }}">{{ $iptc1->IPTC1_NomFR }}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </select><label for="tiersIPTC2">,&nbsp;</label>
                        <select name="tiersiptc2" id="tiersiptc2">
                            <option value="0">---</option>
                            @foreach ($iptc2s as $iptc2)
                                @if( !empty($MetadataSeance[0]->metadata_Id) )
                                    <option value="{{ $iptc2->IPTC2_Id }}" CLASS="{{ $iptc2->IPTC2_IPTC1 }}" {{ ($iptc2->IPTC2_Numero==$MetadataSeance[0]->comadobeiptcSubjectCode ) ? "selected=selected" : '' }}>{{ $iptc2->IPTC2_NomFR }} ({{ $iptc2->IPTC2_Numero }})</option>
                                @else
                                    <option value="{{ $iptc2->IPTC2_Id }}" CLASS="{{ $iptc2->IPTC2_IPTC1 }}">{{ $iptc2->IPTC2_NomFR }} ({{ $iptc2->IPTC2_Numero }})</option>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                    </select><label for="tiersIPTC3">,&nbsp;</label>
                        <select name="tiersiptc3" id="tiersiptc3">
                            <option value="">---</option>
                                @foreach ($iptc3s as $iptc3)
                                    <option value="{{ $iptc3->IPTC3_Id }}" CLASS="{{ $iptc3->IPTC3_IPTC2 }}">{{ $iptc3->IPTC3_NomFR }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                        </select>
            <br>
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
            &nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="{{ $Action['Action'] }}">
            <input type="submit" value="Ajouter">
            <a href="{{ url()->previous() }}">Annuler</a>
        </form>
    @else               
        <h4>&nbsp;Mettre à jour un tiers (artiste, photographe, club...)</h4>
        @if ($errors->any())
            <ul>{!! implode('', $errors->all('<li style="color:red">:message</li>')) !!}</ul>
        @endif
        <form method="POST" action="{!! url('tiersupdatesql') !!}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            &nbsp;<label for="Nom">Nom :&nbsp;</label><input name="tiersNom" type="text" id="tiersNom" maxlength="50" size="50" value="{{ $letiers[0]->tiers_nom }}"><br>
            &nbsp;<label for="Prenom">Prénom :&nbsp;</label><input name="tiersPrenom" type="text" id="tiersPrenom" maxlength="50" size="50" value="{{ $letiers[0]->tiers_prenom }}"><br>
            &nbsp;<label for="Production">Société de production :&nbsp;</label><input type="radio" name="production" value="0" {{ ($letiers[0]->tiers_societeproduction==0 ) ? "checked" : '' }}>&nbsp;Non &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="production" value="1" {{ ($letiers[0]->tiers_societeproduction==1 ) ? "checked" : '' }}>&nbsp;Oui<br>
            @if ( $boiteprod->count()==0 )
                &nbsp;<label for="Production">Pas de boite de production dans la base.</label>
            @else
                &nbsp;<label for="Production">Manager par la boite de production :&nbsp;</label>
                <select name="production" id="production">
                    <option value="">--- choisir une boite de production ---</option>
                    @foreach ($boiteprod as $bprod)
                        <option value="{{ $bprod->tiers_id }}" {{ ($bprod->tiers_id==$letiers[0]->tiers_societeproduction ) ? "selected=selected" : '' }}>{{ $bprod->tiers_nom }} {{ $bprod->ville_name }} ({{ $bprod->zip_code }})</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            @endif
            <br>
            <label for="ville">&nbsp;Ville :&nbsp;</label>
                <select name="ville" id="ville">
                    <option value="">--- choisir une ville ---</option>
                    @foreach ($villes as $ville)
                        <option value="{{ $ville->ville_id }}" {{ ($ville->ville_id==$letiers[0]->tiers_ville ) ? "selected=selected" : '' }}>{{ $ville->ville_name }} ({{ $ville->zip_code }}), {{ $ville->namedept }}-{{ $ville->nom_fr_fr }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select><br>
                <label for="tiersIPTC1">Thème :&nbsp;</label>
                    <select name="tiersiptc1" id="tiersiptc1">
                        <option value="0">Choisissez un thème principal</option>
                        @foreach ($iptc1s as $iptc1)
                            @if( !empty($letiers[0]->tiers_id) )
                                <option value="{{ $iptc1->IPTC1_Id }}" {{ ($iptc1->IPTC1_Id==$letiers[0]->tiers_iptc1) ? "selected=selected" : '' }}>{{ $iptc1->IPTC1_NomFR }}</option>
                            @else
                                <option value="{{ $iptc1->IPTC1_Id }}">{{ $iptc1->IPTC1_NomFR }}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </select><label for="tiersIPTC2">,&nbsp;</label>
                        <select name="tiersiptc2" id="tiersiptc2">
                            <option value="0">---</option>
                            @foreach ($iptc2s as $iptc2)
                                @if( !empty($letiers[0]->tiers_id) )
                                    <option value="{{ $iptc2->IPTC2_Id }}" CLASS="{{ $iptc2->IPTC2_IPTC1 }}" {{ ($iptc2->IPTC2_Id==$letiers[0]->tiers_iptc2 ) ? "selected=selected" : '' }}>{{ $iptc2->IPTC2_NomFR }} ({{ $iptc2->IPTC2_Numero }})</option>
                                @else
                                    <option value="{{ $iptc2->IPTC2_Id }}" CLASS="{{ $iptc2->IPTC2_IPTC1 }}">{{ $iptc2->IPTC2_NomFR }} ({{ $iptc2->IPTC2_Numero }})</option>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                    </select><label for="tiersIPTC3">,&nbsp;</label>
                        <select name="tiersiptc3" id="tiersiptc3">
                            <option value="">---</option>
                                @foreach ($iptc3s as $iptc3)
                                    @if( !empty($letiers[0]->tiers_id) )
                                        <option value="{{ $iptc3->IPTC3_Id }}" CLASS="{{ $iptc3->IPTC3_IPTC2 }}"{{ ($iptc3->IPTC3_Id==$letiers[0]->tiers_iptc3 ) ? "selected=selected" : '' }}>{{ $iptc3->IPTC3_NomFR }}</option>
                                    @else
                                        <option value="{{ $iptc3->IPTC3_Id }}" CLASS="{{ $iptc3->IPTC3_IPTC2 }}">{{ $iptc3->IPTC3_NomFR }}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                        </select>
            <br>
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
            &nbsp;<input name="tiersModif" type="hidden" id="tiersModif" value="{{ $letiers[0]->tiers_id }}">
            <input type="submit" value="Modifier">
            <a href="{{ url()->previous() }}">Annuler</a>
        </form>
    @endif
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-chained/1.0.1/jquery.chained.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#tiersiptc2').chained('#tiersiptc1');
            $('#tiersiptc3').chained('#tiersiptc2');
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```